# Why is the data from a Tor exit node not encrypted?

Tags: encryption, tor, darknet

Tor works in such a way that the data is encrypted by the three nodes. I.e., the entry node, relay and the exit node. But why is it not encrypted from the exit node to the destination server? Is this for speed? Or is it because it's not necessary as tracing back is already impossible?

Comment: How would it negotiate the encryption with the server? Unless you are talking about TLS which is effectively at a different layer.

Comment: The client can use the destination server's public key to encrypt right?

Comment: Which public key? What protocol are you talking about?

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: Even when the user requests `http://example.com/` and some proxy determines that `https://example.com/` also exists, there is no guarantee that it's the same site with the same content served securely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Encryption of traffic exiting Tor and going to the destination server is based on whether the destination server supports encryption, and whether the destination server was addressed on an encrypted port - just as it would be had the traffic not gone through Tor.

Tor cannot magically do something the destination server doesn't support, or that the client did not request to do.